# How can I plot a vector in x and rows from a data frame in y using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector

I have a vector with 40 values and a dataframe with 41 columns, I'd like to plot the vector as x and the row of the dataframe (except for 1 column) as y. The problem is I don't want to put the vector inside the dataframe and ggplot doesn't allow a vector as argument. Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "row of the dataframe (except for 1 column)"? Do you mean a specific row, or all rows (minus those from a specific column)?

Answer (score 1):

GGplot can accept vectors as input. Here is an example of plotting one vector against the first row of a data.frame (with matching length). Does this solve your problem?

```
xval <- rnorm(40)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 41, data = rnorm(5*41)))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = xval, y = unlist(df[1,1:40])))
```

[image]